# asp.net core return an alert on actionresult halts the page form reloading

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to show an alert after my controller did some update with the backend. Once the upload is done, I want the page to reload the model from the server. This all went fine until I tried to give the user some feedback in regards to his action. Now, when I do it like this, the page simply does not reload. So basically without the "Response.WriteAsync()" everything works fine, but there is no feedback for the user. This is what I am doing:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostButton_Yes(IFormCollection data) 
        { 
            var inputSkill = Request.Form["fertigkeitensuchen"];

            var item = new SubCategories
            {
                IsSkill = true,
                BelongsToUserId = userId,
                ValueGer = inputSkill.ToString(),
                BelongsToCategoryId = currentcategoryId
            };

            await new RemoteSubCategoriesService().SaveItemAsync(item);

            await Response.WriteAsync("<script>alert('Skill wurde angelegt, du kannst diesen nun auswählen!')</script>");

            return RedirectToPage("../Jobs/Skills", "UserId", new { id = userId, categoryId = currentcategoryId });
        }
```

Is there maybe a better way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you point clearly, after you upload file in backend successfully, You want show an alert in your view? I think you can do it in your ajax success method.

Comment: Yes, that would be exactly what I want. But if I do it like this, I see the alert but the page doesnt redirect...

Comment: Do you want to show alert before redirect ? For Example, User close this alert then the page will redirect to the specified page.

Comment: yeah that be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to achieve it. Please refer to this simple demo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostButton_Yes(IFormCollection data) 
        { 
            //some code......
            int id = xxxx;
            int categoryId = xxxxx;
           
            //redirect to OnGet() method in Privacy page
            var url =  $"Privacy?id={id}&categoryId={categoryId}";
            return new JsonResult(url);
        }
```

**View**

```
<button type="button" id="button">Test Botton</button>


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            let button = document.getElementById("button");
            button.onclick = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    url: "/Index?handler=Button_Yes",
                    //data: requestData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('Skill wurde angelegt, du kannst diesen nun auswählen!')
                        location.href = data
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

[image]

I hope this simple can help you solve this issue.

BTW: If you get 400 error in ajax in razor page, Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/701086/ajax-post-request-with-razor-pages-and-full-calend).

Comment: Hi @inno, Can this answer solved your issue?